# Flutter ListView doesn't take all space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter and trying to develop my first app.
Here my code:

```
class PopularFoodsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PopularFoodsWidgetState createState() => _PopularFoodsWidgetState();
}

class _PopularFoodsWidgetState extends State<PopularFoodsWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: 600,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: PopularFoodItems(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PopularFoodTiles extends StatelessWidget {
  String name;
  String imageUrl;
  String rating;
  String numberOfRating;
  String price;
  String slug;

  PopularFoodTiles(
      {Key key,
      @required this.name,
      @required this.imageUrl,
      @required this.rating,
      @required this.numberOfRating,
      @required this.price,
     @required this.slug})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(context, ScaleRoute(page: FoodDetailsPage()));
      },
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 5, top: 5, bottom: 5),
            child: Card(
                color: Colors.white,
                elevation: 0,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(5.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                            child: Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5, top: 5),
                              child: Container(
                                height: 28,
                                width: 28,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    color: Colors.white70,
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                        color: Color(0xFFfae3e2),
                                        blurRadius: 25.0,
                                        offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75),
                                      ),
                                    ]),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.favorite,
                                  color: Color(0xFFfb3132),
                                  size: 16,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Center(
                                child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/popular_foods/' +
                                  imageUrl +
                                  ".png",
                              width: 130,
                              height: 140,
                            )),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 5),
                            child: Text(name,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xFF6e6e71),
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                            child: Container(
                              height: 28,
                              width: 28,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  color: Colors.white70,
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: Color(0xFFfae3e2),
                                      blurRadius: 25.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75),
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.near_me,
                                color: Color(0xFFfb3132),
                                size: 16,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 5),
                                child: Text(rating,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color(0xFF6e6e71),
                                        fontSize: 10,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3, left: 5),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.star,
                                      size: 10,
                                      color: Color(0xFFfb3132),
                                    ),
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.star,
                                      size: 10,
                                      color: Color(0xFFfb3132),
                                    ),
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.star,
                                      size: 10,
                                      color: Color(0xFFfb3132),
                                    ),
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.star,
                                      size: 10,
                                      color: Color(0xFFfb3132),
                                    ),
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.star,
                                      size: 10,
                                      color: Color(0xFF9b9b9c),
                                    ),
                                  ],    
                                ),    
                              ),
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 5),
                                child: Text("($numberOfRating)",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color(0xFF6e6e71),
                                        fontSize: 10,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 5, right: 5),
                            child: Text('\$' + price,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xFF6e6e71),
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PopularFoodItems extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      children: <Widget>[
        PopularFoodTiles(
            name: "Fried Egg",
            imageUrl: "ic_popular_food_1",
            rating: '4.9',
            numberOfRating: '200',
            price: '15.06',
            slug: "fried_egg"),
        PopularFoodTiles(
            name: "Mixed Vegetable",
            imageUrl: "ic_popular_food_3",
            rating: "4.9",
            numberOfRating: "100",
            price: "17.03",
            slug: ""),
        PopularFoodTiles(
            name: "Salad With Chicken",
            imageUrl: "ic_popular_food_4",
            rating: "4.0",
            numberOfRating: "50",
            price: "11.00",
            slug: ""),
        PopularFoodTiles(
            name: "Mixed Salad",
            imageUrl: "ic_popular_food_5",
            rating: "4.00",
            numberOfRating: "100",
            price: "11.10",
            slug: ""),
          PopularFoodTiles(
            name: "Red meat,Salad",
            imageUrl: "ic_popular_food_2",
            rating: "4.6",
            numberOfRating: "150",
            price: "12.00",
            slug: ""),
        PopularFoodTiles(
            name: "Mixed Salad",
            imageUrl: "ic_popular_food_5",
             rating: "4.00",
            numberOfRating: "100",
            price: "11.10",
            slug: ""),
        PopularFoodTiles(
            name: "Potato,Meat fry",
            imageUrl: "ic_popular_food_6",
            rating: "4.2",
            numberOfRating: "70",
            price: "23.0",
            slug: ""),
        PopularFoodTiles(
            name: "Fried Egg",
            imageUrl: "ic_popular_food_1",
            rating: '4.9',
            numberOfRating: '200',
            price: '15.06',
            slug: "fried_egg"),
        PopularFoodTiles(
            name: "Red meat,Salad",
            imageUrl: "ic_popular_food_2",
            rating: "4.6",
            numberOfRating: "150",
            price: "12.00",
            slug: ""),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to display a list of food on a page where I have 2 Widgets: one for the search form and one for ListView.
The problem is that my list can't take all the available space on the screen:[image]

I tried to change the height from 400 to 600, it looks better now so I can scroll down, but I still not able to see all items...
[image]
Any suggestion plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting 600, can you calculate the correct available height for the list view?
Like this,

```
height : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height 
           - Your_top_bar_height_including_searchBar 
           - Bottom_TabBar_Height
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the container with an expanded widget

```
class PopularFoodsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PopularFoodsWidgetState createState() => _PopularFoodsWidgetState();
}

class _PopularFoodsWidgetState extends State<PopularFoodsWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: PopularFoodItems(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a code example or more details to make your answer more complete.

Comment: That is unfortunately wrong, `Expanded` requires children parameter which is not there, and also after adding it that will throw an exception...